# How to notify clients (Java,C#) using a WSDL based Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, long-polling

I have to implement a webservice which will be used by different clients written using several languages (e.g. Java,C#) and frameworks.

Because of this i decided to use JAX-WS and the Apache CXF Framework to create an WSDL first webservice.

Now my problem is that the webservice has to notify all clients whenever the user performed certain actions on one of them (like adding an element to the database).

After some research I found that the technique of long-polling might help me to get this task done. However I'm not sure that this is the best solution and that this one will work on all target plattforms.

Is the technique of long-polling suited in a Webservice (WSDL) context or is there another method widely used and supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long polling or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) techniques are best used for this scenario, Web services are stateless and don't support pushing data to clients without heavy modification of the hosting service, i.e. IIS, Apache... etc.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts